# Bottom layout constraint issue

Tags: swift, autolayout, storyboard

I have a image at the bottom of a view controller. tab bar is visible in the view controller. bottom contraint of image is like this . image.bottom = bottomLayoutGuide.top - 2 
intially it comes ok but when user click on another tab and come back. image goes under the tab bar. what could be the reason , how to give bottom constraint in such a way , it always come 2 pixel abobe bottom.

Answer (score -1):

Your view's origin (0, 0) is at its top-left corner, and the y value increases as you go down the screen. If you want your image view to be above the bottom layout guide, your constraint needs to be `bottomLayoutGuide.top - 2`

Comment: sorry contraint is already that. I have edited in question as well.